Screen Flow Validate Input
I've tried many things, but cannot figure out why this is not showing the error.
Requested_Credit_to_Apply is a currency input field.  Expected value will be a positive number.
forPositiveTotalCredits is a formula variable where I just get the absolute of the varTotalCredits variable (because that will appear as a negative). Both variables are currency.
All currency elements are 2 decimal points.
In addition to the screen shot below, I've also tried: {!Requested_Credit_to_Apply} > ABS({!varTotalCredits}) and {!Requested_Credit_to_Apply} <= -{!varTotalCredits}

When I tested, the total credits were -$39.00 and I'm trying to input $55.00 and I'm not seeing the error.

{!Requested_Credit_to_Apply} <= {!forPositiveTotalCredits}
That is what worked.
